# IOPS :maximum number of memory blocks per second?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

From this [IOPS blog](https://searchstorage.techtarget.com/definition/IOPS-input-output-operations-per-second)

> IOPS (input/output operations per second) is the standard unit of
>   measurement for the maximum number of reads and writes to
>   non-contiguous storage locations. IOPS is frequently referenced by
>   storage vendors to characterize performance in solid-state drives
>   (SSD), hard disk drives (HDD) and storage area networks where Higher 
>   IOPS  means better read and write performance.

My understanding is when we say maximum number of reads and writes for HDD, it means maximum number of memory block reads and writes per second. Is that correct ? Also why only non-contiguous storage locations are considered but not contiguous storage locations ?

Comment: If you're going to lift a quote from somebody, then it's proper to provide an attribute.

Comment: It's not as *"standard"* as you claim, and random (i.e. *"non-contiguous"*) accesses are not exclusively mandated.  HDDs (and SSDs) are random-access devices, as opposed to sequential access.  Every storage block has an address (e.g. LBA), and any block can be specified by its address for the next R/W operation.  During a performance test of a random-access device, accessing non-adjacent and/or non-contiguous blocks would make sense in order to evaluate access (i.e. seek & rotational-latency) times.

Comment: For a more-realistic definition for IOPS see https://kb.sandisk.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/8153/~/input%2Foutput-operations-per-second-%28iops%29-defined

Comment: @sawdust The link you mentioned just says that `it is s a common performance measurement used to benchmark computer storage devices like hard disk drives (HDD), solid state drives (SSD), and storage area networks (SAN).` But what is the measurement, it does not define that ?

Comment: The quote you cited also uses the word *"measurement"*.  Why aren't you questioning that?  *"it does not define that ?"*  -- Then you need to read that page again more carefully.